# Adding metric labels in prometheus on the fly

Tags: go, label, prometheus, metrics, dynamically-generated

I have a counter metric in prometheus. I want to add lables to it dynamically for example if my request comes `http://abc123.com/{p1}` ,I want my custom_metric_name to store  `{statuscode=200, p1=p1Value , host="abc123"}` and if request comes http://def123.com/{p2} . I want custom_metric_name to store `{statuscode=200, p2=p2Value , host="def123"}` but `custom_metric_name` will be shared metric by both.

I am trying still not able to get answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) or [metric_relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) in your Prometheus config.

It would look like the following:

```
- source_labels: [request_origin]
  regex: 'http://(\w+)/.*'
  replacement: '${1}'
  target_label: host
```

See also this [article](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names) showing usage of relabelling.

Comment: this is not adding but changing a label, isn't it?

Comment: It is because `target_label` indicates new label to create.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic labels can be easily added to the exported Prometheus metrics when using [github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics) Go package:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics"
)

// CountRequest increments `requests_total{statuscode="statusCode", host="host", path="path"}` Prometheus counter
func CountRequest(statusCode int, host, path string) {
  s := fmt.Sprintf(`requests_total{statuscode="%d", host=%q, path=%q}`, statusCode, host, path)
  metrics.GetOrCreateCounter(s).Inc()
}
```